# How do I ensure my upgraded server remains on the LTS?

Tags: upgrade, lts, release-management

I'd like to upgrade my server from non-LTS (Saucy) to the new LTS (Trusty Tahr).

In other words, once Ubuntu 14.10 will be out (next scheduled release after 14.04), I would like to remain on the LTS branch and not go to 14.10.

Is there anything special I should do (or should not do)?

Is this just a matter of **not** running `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` once 14.10 will be out, or will config files need to be adjusted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you upgrade all you need to do is make sure you're being notified of LTS releases only. You can do this by checking the file `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`:

```
[DEFAULT]
# Default prompting behavior, valid options:
#
#  never  - Never check for a new release.
#  normal - Check to see if a new release is available.  If more than one new
#           release is found, the release upgrader will attempt to upgrade to
#           the release that immediately succeeds the currently-running
#           release.
#  lts    - Check to see if a new LTS release is available.  The upgrader
#           will attempt to upgrade to the first LTS release available after
#           the currently-running one.  Note that this option should not be
#           used if the currently-running release is not itself an LTS
#           release, since in that case the upgrader won't be able to
#           determine if a newer release is available.
Prompt=lts
```

Ensure `Prompt=` is set to `lts`.

Running `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` will never upgrade you to the newer release unless you manually change your `/etc/apt/sources.list` or if you do a `do-release-upgrade`, so you should be good to go.